# Angular6 posting json to CakePHP

Tags: angular6, cakephp-3.x

Good Day everyone, I have a login form with username and password.

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormLogin(loginForm)">

    <div class="md-form">
      <input type="email" id="materialLoginFormEmail" class="form-control" formControlName="username" #username>
      <label for="materialLoginFormEmail">E-mail</label>
    </div>

    <div class="md-form">
      <input type="password" id="materialLoginFormPassword" class="form-control" formControlName="password" #password>
      <label for="materialLoginFormPassword">Password</label>
    </div>

    <!-- Sign in button -->
      <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-rounded btn-block my-4 waves-effect z-depth-0" type="submit" style="height: 40px; line-height: 40px; box-sizing: border-box;" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" (click)="username.value=''; password.value=''"><a>Sign in</a></button>

</form>
```

and in my login component I try to directly post it into an http.

```
onFormLogin() {

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('username', this.loginForm.value.username);
formData.append('password', this.loginForm.value.password);

this.http.post('http://localhost/bookstore/customerlogs/add', formData, 
httpOptions)
.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('Got some data from input ', data);
}, (error) => {
  console.log('Error! ', error);
});

console.warn('Username:', this.loginForm.value.username);
console.warn('Password:', this.loginForm.value.password);

}
```

at this point I want to receive those inputted data into the database where my customerlogscontroller.php is.(CakePHP)

```
public function add()
{
  //how to accept json from Angular component ?
}
```

Comment: can you explain your problem, whar you have tried so far and what the results are#ß

Comment: Thank you for your respone @jan-seins the above code is what I've tried, but it's an empty in customerlogs.php(cakephp) for i really don't know what to put in receiving the json file from login.component(angular)

Comment: You may want to [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52578971/edit) with a little more info about where exactly (code wise) your problem lies. The title and the intro sounds like you're having an angular problem, your comment sounds like you're having a CakePHP problem (maybe **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#request** helps), but it's not clear in any case what exactly the problem looks like that you're facing. Using pseudo-code can often help to describe problems if you're having a hard time formulating them!

Comment: I have my form with an input of "username" and "password" in Angular as a json then I just want to post those inputted data into my database were I'm using CakePHP as my server side